# Do I have to unwind the 'stack' in storyboard during logout?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have a storyboard setup as such:

TitleScreen
(push)
LoginScreen
(CustomSegue)
UITabBarViewController (root view here is a UINavigationController)
(modal)
SettingsView
(CustomSegue)
TitleScreen

So my goal is to have a "`Logout`" button in the `SettingsView` and it will take the user back to the `TitleScreen`.

However, when i tried this, after logging out, the `TitleScreen` will not transition to the `LoginScreen` anymore. It works when starting up the app, but not after i 'Logout'.

Does that mean, i have to somehow unwind the Storyboard 'stack'? If so, how could it be done with 1 transition?

Idea: Send a notification to the `AppDelegate`, via `NSNotificationCenter`, to recreate the `rootViewControler`.

Anyone done this before?

Comment: Sending a notification to the app delegate does work. 

The app delegate must first dismiss the rootViewController. On completion of that, re-initialize it with the Storyboard's initial view controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd put the navigation controller right at the start of the design and use **popToRootViewController:animated:** to get back to the root.  If you don't want the navigation bar showing for the earlier views like the login page, you can always choose to hide it.

I do something similar in my [tutorial here](http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part-2/) where I have a nav controller for both tabs at the top of the design, except I don't hide anything as it's just for tutorial.

Comment: I did think about this but quickly realize that `UINavigationController` should never contain a `UITabBarController`. Since one of `UITabBarController`'s children might be a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: No, i'd also have both the tab bar and nav controllers at the top of this hierarchy. I do something similar in my tutorial. I've edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I would re-think your storyboard layout here a bit. The title screen and login screens are essentially just modal views on top of the main part of your app, the `UITabBarController`. I would have the `UITabBarController` be the initial view controller in the storyboard and then conditionally present the title view/login screen modally as soon as the application finishes launching.

Now with this design, showing the login screen is as simple as performing any modal segue. You may want to think about using delegation from the settings view controller to notify the presenting view controller that the user logged out and that the login view controller should be presented.

Comment: I did try this but i realized then the implementation of the view in `UITabBarController` won't be as clean since it now has to know about the 'before sign in' state.

Comment: As for the delegation from settings to the modal's parent, i'd prefer using `NSNotificationCenter`. It's essentially the EventBus pattern and much cleaner and more suited to my taste.